# Why does my Python CGI code print nothing when run in XAMPP Apache server?

Tags: python, apache, xampp, cgi

I am trying to run this simple "Hello World" code on an XAMPP Apache server as part of this [Python School tutorial](http://www.pythonschool.net/server-side-scripting/create-your-first-server-side-script/) on server-side scripting. It throws up no server errors, but all I get is a blank white screen. I have tried this in both Chrome and MS Edge. Is there anything I am overlooking as to why this isn't working or is this an overly complicated way to do this?

```
#!C:\python34\python.exe
import cgi

def htmlTop():
    print("""Content-type: text/html\n\n
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <title>My first server-side page<\title>
        <body>""")

def htmlBottom():
    print("""<\body>
        <\html>""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    htmlTop()
    print("Hello World")
    htmlBottom()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `__name__` isn't `__main__` when being executed from XAMPP?  Try printing the value of `__name__`.

Comment: Also your ending tags use the wrong slash.  Use forward slashes, not backslashes.

Comment: Thank you very much John, it works now I've changed the backslashes!